# godror SQL driver, and a slice of structs

Tags: oracle, go

I am using Go to open a file with multiple JSON entries, parse the file into a slice with a custom type, then insert the slice data into an Oracle database. According to the godror documentation at https://godror.github.io/godror/doc/tuning.html, I *should* be able to feed a slice into the insert command, and have the database/sql Exec method iterate thru the struct for me. I am at a loss for how to do this. I am sure there is a simple solution to this.

To slightly complicate things, I have a database column that is not in the struct for the host name of the computer the app is running on. This column should be filled in for every row the app inserts. In other words, every row of this table needs to have a column filled in with the host name of the machine is running on. Is there a more elegant way to do this than to just add a 'hostname' field to my struct that has the running system's host name, over and over again?

What follows is a simplified version of my code.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"

    _ "github.com/godror/godror"
)

type MyType struct {
    var1 string `json:"var1"`
    var2 string `json:"var2"`
}

func main() {
    hostname, err := os.Hostname()

    if err != nil {
        //log.Println("Error when getting host name")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    mySlice := parseFile("/path/to/file", false)

    db, err := sql.Open("godror", "user/pass@oraHost/oraDb")
    sql := `INSERT INTO mytable (var1, var2, host) values (:1 :2 :3)`

    // this is the line where everything breaks down, and i am not sure
    // what should go here.
    _, err = db.Exec(sql, mySlice[var1], mySlice[var2], hostname)
}

func parseFile(filePath string, deleteFile bool) []MyType {
    // a few lines of code that opens a text file, parses it into a slice
    // of type MyType, and returns it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure, if you already went through, does this test case, TestExecuteMany help ?  mentioned in https://github.com/godror/godror/blob/master/z_test.go has example usage for array insert.

```
res, err := tx.ExecContext(ctx,
        `INSERT INTO `+tbl+ //nolint:gas
            ` (f_id, f_int, f_num, f_num_6, F_num_5_2, F_vc, F_dt)
            VALUES
            (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7)`,
        ids, ints, nums, int32s, floats, strs, dates)
```

for batch insert of structs:

https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx